# Do intensifiers in Turkish, Roamance, Semitic, Turkish inflect with their focus in pre-predicate positions?

Tags: syntax

I read that *In languages like Slavic, Romance, Semitic, Turkish, Persian, intensifiers inflect and show agreement with their focus*. For example:

Ali profesör-ün kendi-si-ni sav-un-du.
Ali professor-gen self-3sg:poss-acc defend-past-3sg
‘Ali defended the professor himself’.

[Source: *Reflexives: Forms and Functions*, edited by Zygmunt Frajzyngier and Traci S. Curl]

I wonder if these intensifiers also inflect and show agreement in the pre-predicate positions? (For example, John ***himself*** proposed this.)

And do they need to attach to the focus strictly, or are they able to float around without altering the meaning of the expression?
Examples will be extremely appreciated!

Comment: I don’t think they generally appear in pre-predicate position in Romance – at least it sounds rather unnatural to me when I try it out in languages like French and Spanish. But if they do, I’m certain they would still inflect; it would be quite bizarrely un-Romance for them not to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I myself cannot speak Romance and Spanish, so I have no idea how it works in those languages. Your answer is definitely helpful.

Comment: Of course, Romance languages have lost cases outside pronouns (and intensifiers are not pronominal in Romance), so the only inflection would be for gender and number agreement, where the situation is similar to English – that is, it would be just as bizarre not to have agreement in Romance as it would in English (“*Susan himself proposed this”, “*The children himself proposed this”).

Comment: Got it. So it still inflects with the NP. Then can we say *Suan proposed this herself * in Romance? (Move the intensifer around)

Comment: Yes, normally we’d expect the intensifier to be at the end as in your example. It may be possible to move it around, but I think it’s at least much less common than in English. In French, for example, I expect you could say “Susanne, elle-même, l’a proposé”, but it would be more common to say “Susanne l’a proposé elle-même”.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the message! It's a bit like English in that intensifier can show up at the very end of a sentence, which is not allowed in Chinese actually. However, in Chinese, the intensifier does not inflect and does not show up at the very end of a sentence.  So, does intensifier also show up at the end when subject is a pronoun, for example,  *She herself went to the mall*,   Is it similar in Spanish?

Comment: I believe so, yes; _elle l’a proposé elle-même_ sounds right enough to me. In Spanish, Italian and Portuguese, pronominal subjects tend to be elided altogether, so you’d just have _lo ha propuesto ella misma_. Note that in Romance, the intensifier (which is the same word as ‘same’) is always used with the disjunctive/emphatic pronouns, never with the weak used for subject and object. So _*je-même_ is not possible, only _moi-même_, which is then added after the subject (as in _elle… elle-même_ above).

Comment: Hi Janus. I also wonder if French or Spanish have two meanings of reflexive aside from its anaphoric use. For example, in English, *John himself did this* can mean John rather than somebody else did it. While *John did it himself* can mean that Jogh did it by himself. So I would like to know if reflexives in French and Spanish can convey these two types of meanings, and if so, what positions they are in?  Again, thank you so much for your informative answers, which are really fun to know.